# How to specify start up option with mysql.server start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using mariadb, and mysql.server start
I want to specify a start up option as given in the mariadb documentation:

innodb_page_size=4k

however, when I try:

mysql.server start --innodb_page_size=4k

this doesn't work
I also tried to put innodb_page_size in my.cnf under the [mysqld] tag, and this also resulted in a error when I tried to startup the mysql server.

Where exactly can I specify these startup options?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I think the page_size must be set on the _very first_ startup, because there is no way to change it later.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistyped the option. Indeed for Mysql/MariaDB each option has a name for the command line's startup options, and the my.cnf configuration file

- use `--innodb-page-size` for passing the option from the command line
- use `innodb_page_size` for passing the option from my.cnf configuration file

Options taken from [mysql 5.7 version's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size).

Best regards.